# why _self turn out to be different values?

Tags: javascript

```
    function Carousel(){

        this.prevbtn=$('#prevbtn');

        _self=this;

        this.prevbtn.click(function(){
            console.log(_self);   //Carousel object
            _self.piclist.animate({
                console.log(_self);   //error 
            })
        })
    }
    var z=new Carousel();
```

this is my js code and have import jq before. I want to know why _self will be the two different values? one is right and the other is error?

Comment: Why did he get a downvote ? the wrote he code his question is clear.. no reason to downvote. we are here to get/give help.

Comment: always use `var` to declare local variables. If you use `_self` somewhere else will overwrite the global one you are using

Comment: [Use documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntaxis error

```
_self.piclist.animate({
     console.log(_self);   //error 
})
```

`console.log` is not inside a executable block

Comment: console.log() is not the default functon of js?